# Trouble printing unicode values

Tags: java, unicode

I am trying to printsubscripts in java but whenever I type in the unicode value for said subscript and print it I get a "?" For example the code down below would print Na? instead of Na₂

```
System.out.println("Na\u2082");
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this. I've looked everywhere online and have absolutely no idea why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Works for me.](https://ideone.com/LC1AFZ) How are you testing?

Comment: What you see on the console is irrelevant if it doesn't support UTF-8 characters.

Comment: I am using jGrasp. Also I apologize about the previous title, I was changing something else I was going to submit before I found the answer and forgot to edit the title.